# Set a local static IP address on a network interface and have it permanent even after restart

Tags: opensuse, ip, network-interface

I have openSUSE 13.2. My laptop connects to the internet through a WiFi network but I have an embedded device which I need to connect to it through the ethernet interface. It has an IP address of `192.168.2.50`. The problem is I set the IP address of the interface using this:

```
ifconfig enp3s0 192.168.2.64 netmask 255.255.255.0
```

This works fine but when the device disconnects or reboot, the connection I made is lost and the PC attempts to connect through the ethernet interface and my internet connection is lost. I have to unplug the cable, apply the command and reconnect the cable to connect to my device while not interrupting the internet connection. So is is possible to set a permanent IP so it should not interfere with other interfaces and connections ?

Comment: Are you using _ifup_ or _NetworkManager_? You can check that in YaST -> Network Settings

Answer (score 1):

If it's connected to the router, many routers allow a permanent address to be assigned to a device based on its MAC address. Addresses will still be assigned by DHCP but the router will always give the device with that MAC address the IP address you specify.

Comment: It is not connected to a router. Direct connection to my PC

Answer (score 0):

commands which you have to fire are : 
1. Check your NIC

## ifconfig

2. Choose one and set it with ip which you want to give

   ## ifconfig enp0s8 192.168.1.34
3. go to

   ## cd /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/
4. edit NIC file

   ## vim ifcfg-enp0s8

   do -->

'IPADDR' = 192.168.1.34 
 'NETMASK'= 255.255.255.0 
 'ONBOOT' = yes 
 'BOOTPROTO'= 'static' 
5. done

Comment: Please take the time to [learn how to properly format your posts](http://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help).